# How to get values from mule payload which i am getting from mule database connector

Tags: mule

please suggest how to write a java class to read mule payload and read the values from the same and assign them to a DTO so i can return the same.

How can send back the DTO with values from Database , i am facing issue in reading the payload or transforming it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using enterprise edition then you can use DataWeave to convert resultset into pojos. Database connector returns ArrayList of Hashmap for rows. You can iterate over this list and create pojo's, eg. -

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload map {
({id: $.id,
name: $.name}) as :object {class:'com.my.PersonPojo'}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read payload from database using MEL map syntax instead of going for java component.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Get your payload in java by this

```
List<String> list = eventContext.getMessage().getPayload();
```

Assign it to a list and iterate it and load it to `list<DTOObject>`

```
List<DTOObject> dtos = new ArrayList<DTOObject>();
for(String eachValue : list) {
   dto.setValue(eachValue);
   dtos.add(dto);
}
return dtos;
```

This will return the list `dtos` to the payload and you can grab them in the next component.
If you want to get them from anywhere in the flow, set the list to session variable from your java

```
eventContext.getMessage().setProperty("dtoList", dtos, PropertyScope.SESSION);
```

Grab it like `sessionVars.dtolist` to get the list. Iterate and get each values.